# Не воспринимает русские названия столбцов из файла csv

Tags: python, pandas, кодировка, tkinter, matplotlib

У меня имеется csv файл

```
Отсчеты;Канал 0, В;
0;-0,273;
1;-0,039;
2;0,049;
3;0,264;
4;0,000;
5;-0,059;
6;-0,254;
7;0,039;
8;0,039;
9;0,234;
10;-0,020;
```

Дело в том, что мне необходимо вывести график на основании этих данных. Вот функция:

```
def grafic():
    try:
        plt.style.use('ggplot')  # графики
        plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15, 5)  # размер картинок
        file_name = fd.askopenfilename()
        f = open(file_name)
        fixed_df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=';', decimal=",", encoding='latin1')
        fixed_df["Канал 0, В"].plot(figsize=(15, 10))
        f.close()
        plt.show()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        mb.showinfo("Внимание", "Файл не загружен")
```

Дело в том, что когда я указываю столбец на русском языке, выдаёт ошибку

```
KeyError: 'В'
```

Дело в том, что когда я указываю название столбца на английском языке, такой проблемы нет, и график нормально строится. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте ту кодировку, которая была использована при сохранении файла:

```
fixed_df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=';', decimal=",", encoding='utf-8')
```

или:

```
fixed_df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=';', decimal=",", encoding='cp1251')
```

Comment: с utf-8 пытался сделать, не работало. Но вот с кодировкой "cp1251" всё работает! Большое спасибо!